# properties file in src/main/test is not being recognized by doing mvn clean test

Tags: java, spring, maven

Failed to parse configuration class [com.visa.vbv.ds.dao.TestHibernateConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I get above error on doing mvn test. File is present in my src/main/test

Comment: the correct folder is `src/test/resources`. BTW: please share a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

By convention Maven uses the following directory structure:

```
src
|__ main            // production 
|    |__ java       // production code 
|    |__ resources  // production resources
|
|__ test            // test 
     |__ java       // test code 
     |__ resources  // test resources
```

So the chances are that you've placed your properties file in the wrong place.